# Python: Problems mocking an instance

Tags: python

I am having problem mocking an object to test a descriptor.

This is the code of the descriptor:

```
class Text(object):
    def __init__(self, default_value=u'', validators=[]):
        self.validators = validators
        self._value = default_value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
         for validator in self.validators:
               validator(value).validate()
```

this is the test:

```
def test_text_validator_raises_exception(self):
   validator = Mock()
   validator.validate.side_effect = ValidationError()
   text = Text(validators=[validator])
   self.assertRaises( ValidationError, text__set__, (text, '') )
```

**Edit:**
The function has () in the code I did a typo when copying the code.

The error I got was that **set**() takes exactly 3 arguments. But I noticed in the answers that I shouldn't pass a tuple as a last argument.

But It also isn't working when I called validator('').validate() inside the test function.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `validator` in `Text` is an object factory e.g., class object
- `validator` in the `test_..` function is used as a concrete instance -- the product of an object factory.

You should give to `Text()` something that returns objects with `.validate` method not the objects themselves:

```
def test_text_validator_raises_exception(self):
    validator = Mock()
    validator.validate.side_effect = ValidationError()
    text = Text(validators=[Mock(return_value=validator)])
    self.assertRaises(ValidationError, text.__set__, text, '')
```

Comment: This is actually what I was trying to ask. Was trying to figure out how to let mock return a class instead of an object. In your example doesn't Mock(return_value=validator) also return the instance of the object instead of class?

Comment: Tried it and it works, thanks a lot. Going to try and not make any questions anymore when I am in a hurry since it all got a little messy. Thanks again.

Comment: @Pickels: Consider: `f = Mock(return_value=validator)`. Here's `f` is an object that returns `validator` when you *call* it e.g., `f(value) == validator`. `f` and `f()` are different things in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to put () after function name

Comment: Yes, `def test_text_validator_raises_exception` certainly needs `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way to mock an instance is just "You call yourself an *instance*?"

Seriously, though, `def test_text_validator_raises_exception:` should be `def test_text_validator_raises_exception():`

But what problem are you having with it, as the first commenter asked?